# Problems with form and POST

Tags: html, file-upload, webforms, python-3.x, wsgi

i am facing problems with my form, i wrote a app in Python3.1 and when i make a GET or a POST via AJAX works pefectly but when i' ve try to do the same thing with the form-way the environ['wsgi.input'] give me this:

```
-----------------------------4974611941277794205934495116--\r
```

in the first time i think this was because the file what i was try to upload but after i eliminate the file element and give me the same thing what means this i let you the code of the form:

```
<iframe id="hidden-frm" name="hidden-frm" style="display: none;">
</iframe>
<form ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" action="Gate.py?bt=upload" method="POST" name="input" target="hidden-frm">    
    <input id="testtxt" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Presiona aqui!"/>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the environment you would like to work in? Ie. Is it a WSGI app using wsgiref to serve, or perhaps CGI via Apache, or FastCGI via nginx?

Comment: It's a WSGI app using wsgiref to serve, and the main problem is when i've try to save an ecoded file, fixed the problem of the question, but thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

That encoding is the result of the `enctype="multipart/form-data`, when I suspect you are actually expecting the default encoding of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (ie. `key=value&key2=value2`).

If you do not need the file input (which requires the multipart encoding) then simply remove the `enctype` from your form tag, otherwise you will need to parse the multipart input. The stdlib `cgi.FieldStorage` is one solution for Python 2.x, but I do not know the status of that particular class for Python 3.x (it used to be broken, IIRC).

Comment: This doesn' t work, but with the enctype it works, now my problem is with the extract in the cgi, theres no other way to extract?